# How to declare constants to use as bound variables in Z3_mk_forall_const?

Tags: z3

Suppose I want to universally quantify x and y in the following formula:

```
f(x,y) <=> x=y
```

using *`Z3_mk_forall_const`* . I will have to first construct the formula above, which requires constants x and y of type *`Z3_ast`* . Using *`Z3_mk_const`* to create x and y results in a global declaration. I would ideally like to avoid that. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an alternative; you can use [Z3_mk_forall](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga7e975b7d7ac96de1db73d8f71166c663) which uses [de-Brujin variable indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index). Instead of constants, you can create indexed variables using 
[Z3_mk_bound](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga1d4da8849fca699b345322f8ee1fa31e) and then pass an array of their sorts (sorts) and names (decl_names) to mk_forall or mk_exists.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. I understand that _`Z3_mk_forall`_ can be used to create universally quantified formula with de-Brujin indices as bound variables. However, this is approach is cumbersome for nested quantifiers, as it requires "shifting" the indices. On the other hand, quantified formulas with unique bound variables can be composed trivially. So, I ideally want to use _`Z3_mk_forall_const`_ without creating global declarations.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no direct way of doing that. However, the constants used in creating quantifiers are just there for convencience; internally everything is translated into de-Brujin indices anyways. So, once you have created the quantifier, it should be safe to reuse the constants elsewhere.